# Converting from Excel to HDF5 using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, hdf5

I want to extract the content of an Excel document into a pandas dataframe and then write that dataframe into an HDF5 file. To do so, I've done this:

```
xls_df = pd.read_excel(fn_xls)
xls_df.to_hdf(fn_h5, 'table', format='table', mode='w')
```

This results in the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot serialize the column [Col1] because
>   its data contents are [unicode] object dtype

I tried using convert.objects() on the dataframe from the Excel file, but this doesn't work (and convert.objects() is deprecated). Are there any suggestions on going about this?

Here is a little information on the Excel file:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 101 entries, 0 to 100
Data columns (total 5 columns):
Col1                   101 non-null object
Col2                   101 non-null object
Col3                   94 non-null float64
Col4                   98 non-null object
Col5                   93 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2), object(3)
```

The first and second columns are strings, the fourth column has 1 string but is mostly integers and the third and fifth columns are integers.

Comment: Show some sample entries of the dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mixed string and integer data types in column "Col4" are cause an error when converting to HDF5 in "table" format.

To save in hdf5 "tables" format you need to convert the numbers in Col4 to floats (and strings to NaN):

`df["Col4"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Col4"], errors="coerce")`

Or convert everything in the column to strings:

`df["Col4"] = df["Col4"].astype(str)`

Or use the "fixed" hdf5 format which allows columns to have mixed datatypes. This saves the mixed datatype column in in the python pickle format, and currently gives a PerformanceWarning.

`df.to_hdf(outpath, 'yourkey', format='fixed', mode='w')`